# How to open .conf files with File Expert?

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, file-management, root-access, text-editor

I have a rooted Android device running 4.0.3. I bought full version of File Expert in order to browse root file system.

I navigate to a `.conf` file and want to open it, but the app says *`There is no handler installed on your device for this file format. Would you like File Expert to find one for you?`*.
I select OK, but I get another error: *`Sorry, currently there is no handler for this format...`*.

If I force this file to be openend as text file `Open as text`, and choose FE Text Editor, nothing happens.

Any chance to make this work or I'll have to buy another app for this?

Comment: Any chance you don't mind being suggested different app ?

Comment: @roxan Which app did you have in mind?

Comment: I use ES File Explorer,its free has tons of feature and if you go to settings you have option to mount root folder as well.

Comment: @roxan Can it browser root directories? I set Enable root but no root content appears. Does it require to buy root browser plugin as well as some other root apps?

Comment: I've set default location to / so every time I open it, I get inside /. No it doesn't need any plugin or so.

Comment: @roxan Funny, but I cannot see the content of root nor it ever ask about gaining root priliveges (like other apps do).

Comment: @roxan Found it. I was selecting the wrong permission. It's working now and I can see the files. I get said when I think that I paid the same features when I have this one for free. And the paid one did not work :((

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While File Expert is a good app there are ***great*** apps out there.

I was hesitant to switch because I didn't want to install another app for ftp sharing, but I discovered [Solid Explorer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=pl.solidexplorer). It's the best File manager app for android, bar none.
It has an exceptional text editor with optional monospace font(!), size setting and line wraps can be disabled! And of course Root support out of the box. All for the great price of `0$.` (Thought it's in beta, so that might change.)

It also includes FTP/SFTP/SMB/CIFS browsing, support for Google Drive, Dropbox, Box and SkyDrive. And so many other goodies that there's not enough space here to list it all.

Comment: I'll definitely give it a try

Answer (score 1):

File Expert at the moment cannot open such files.

I recommend using the app called [ES File Explorer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=xcxin.filexpert)! It's free and you just enable root option in the Properties, and you have root access.

**DO NOT** buy File Expert's root plugin as it's a waste of money!!!